# How to create shortcut for "⌘+¨" or "⌘+^" in BetterTouchTool?

Tags: bettertouchtool

Adding a shortcut for "⌘+P" or most other letters (different than P) just works fine. However, if I want to register a shortcut for "⌘+¨" or "⌘+^" BetterTouchTool prohibits to register this as an input. It aborts and plays the sound for unacceptable input (system sound).

What can you suggest to record a shortcut for these keys? Is there a way to edit a file somewhere?

Comment: Are you using the latest version (2.0.2, as of Jan 31).  I could register both of the keypresses you mentioned.  Don't know if this is new or not, though.

Comment: Yes I'm using 2.0.2. Did you register them as a shortcut or a key sequence?

Comment: I've just seen that i can register these combinations as a key sequence, but not as a shortcut.

Comment: I could register ⌘+¨ and ⌘+^  as a Shortcut in the Keyboard preferences, and as a test, had it trigger another keyboard shortcut (just "a")  Both worked as expected.

Comment: Alright, do you have a US-EN keyboard? Mine is swiss - I don't know if that's the issue. I'll try with an external keyboard.

Comment: I've just seen that I can't even register a shortcut just for the keys: ¨ and ^.

Comment: Actually, a Japanese keyboard.  So the " is shift+2; but the ^ is its own key without any modifier at all.

Comment: I see. One way to get these shortcuts into the system would be that you register them and send me the configuration file - but I don't know whether file sharing is encouraged here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is an unsolvable issue:

https://github.com/fifafu/BetterTouchTool/issues/316